# XHR Requests only start when tab is focused on IOS 7 Safari

Tags: ios, ajax, mobile-safari

Following use case:

1. User clicks button on tab 1
2. App opens popup tab 2 (about:blank)
3. Severeal XMLHttpRequest occur between app on tab1 and server
4. App uses that info to create a form POST request from tab1 with `target=tab2` (`action` is another origin, eg. paypal)
5. Tab 2 loads form response
6. etc

This works pretty much anywhere. On iOS Safari 7 it seems not. 
On iOS Safari 7, the popup opens but stays on `about:blank`, because the XMLHttpRequest doesn't start because the tab1 at that point is no longer focused (the browser shows tab2).
If the user switches back to tab1, the execution resumes and everything works. (but that's not really intuitive).

I cannot create the XMLHTTPRequest before opening the popup, because the popup has to be created as a **direct** consequence of a user action or it will end in the popup blocker. Therefore the flow *"user click starts request, request callback opens popup"* does not work.

Is there a way around this limitation other than restructuring the whole app (eg. loading the http requests from the popup)?